# How to hide a caret in IE? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, hide, caret

While displaying a pop-up window above a wysiwyg editor, the caret (cursor in text area) is still visible under the pop-up window. Any ideas?

Comment: By pop-up window you mean a div-Element on top of the page, right?

Answer (score 3):

First idea coming to my mind is to blur() the textarea or put the focus elsewhere. Of course, I suppose the WYSIWYG editor uses a simple textarea, not a more complex DHTML component.

Comment: I tried blur before asking the question, but then another app gets the focus and the IE window is hidden